# Comparing array of objects and converting from an object to it's primitive type

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to find the lowest value of an array of object from another class and storing that object int into an int type.

I am unsure to how to compare the array values and storing the lowest value into an int.

```
void findlow(Student [] a) {
/* This method will find the lowest score and store it in an   array names 
lowscores. */
    for (int i = 0; i < (a.length - 1); i++) {
        for (int j = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
            if (a[i].equals(a[j])) {
                 lowscores[i] = a[i];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Lowest value of an array of objects? Be more explicit; are the objects numeric? What's your definition of "lowest value"?

Comment: Sort the array, it'll probably give you better performance

Comment: What is the structure of 'Student', you might as well compare the actual property on student rather than attempting to implicitly convert the object... unless you really did make Student inherit from int... tell me you didn't actually make your business object inherit from a primitive type that is not object. Implicit conversions look cool, but make your code hard to read or maintain by other devs.

Answer (score 0):

Use `lowscores[i] = a[i].(whatever integer variable);`. The integer variable should be your getter or public int variable from the Student class. In java, you can't set a int variable to an object, that is why it that line is probably giving you an error.

As for finding the lowest score, get the 1st index of the `a` array then just check if it is less than the next index and if it is set that to a `lowScore` variable.

Answer (score 0):

You have a void method "findlow"; this is confusing because if it's called find____ it should find something.

Break your problem into methods:

1st method - find lowest value of the object you're looking for
2nd method - put the result somewhere

so in your case you might have for the first method

```
public Student lowest(Student[] students) {
    Student result = students[0];
    for (Student s : students) {
        if (s.getProperty() < result.getProperty()) {
            result = s;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

and for the second

```
public void saveStudentInfo(Student student) {
    // do something with the student you found
}
```

so in total

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // ...
    Student s = lowest(students);
    saveStudentInfo(s);
}
```

Comment: In the above code, getProperty() is a getter method on a field of the Student object; maybe in your case it would be getAge where there is a private field such as private int age.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear and ambiguous..

> I'm trying to find the lowest value of an array of object from another
>   class and storing that object int into an int type.

First and foremost, you can easily pass the array (from the *other* class) to your new class.. That's pretty basic; create an object of your *other* class and simply reference the array.

**Example:**
I'll assume the *other* class name is 'Other' and the array is named 'arr' in that class.

```
Other other = new Other();
Student[] student = other.arr;
```

Since you're doing a numerical comparison, I'll also assume your *Student class* has a method that returns a numerical value (say, int). Let's call this method getValue(). Now, this is how your findlow() method should be:

```
int findlow(Student[] a){
    int low = a[0].getValue();
    for(int i = 1; i < a.length; i++){
        if(a[i].getValue() < low){
            low = a[i].getValue();
          }
        }
}//End of method.
```

I hope this helps!

Merry coding!!!